# Switch override and precedence in Windows Installer 3.1 installer

Tags: cmd, installation, windows-installer, command-line-arguments

I want a quiet install and also do not want any prompts for restart, overwrite files etc. So, should I use switches "/norestart", "/overwriteoemprompting", "/passive" etc. if I am using "/quiet" switch?

Please see the screenshot attached below:

[image]

Will "/quiet" switch ensure that there is no prompt for restart, file overwrite etc.? I mean, are "/norestart", "/overwriteoemprompting", "/passive" switches required if "/quiet" is used?

Is there any precedence for switches?

I need this to install .net 2.0 in windows xp.

Comment: Are you updating a server? Are you including the runtime with your own setup? What is the use case scenario? I added a long answer that I discovered didn't answer your question (deleted).

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use the other set of command line options, they seem to have a better explanation because things like /passive are a combination of them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options

Quiet means quiet - it won't prompt for reboot it will just do it. Passive sets /qb!- and REBOOTPROMPT=s, which conflicts with quiet meaning /qn. So just pick the set from the traditional commands at that link and you should be good to go.